# Magento2 how to override collection

Tags: magento2, collection, overrides, grid

I want to build a grid that show information from "**directory_country_region**" table but show only for "**country_id**" with id = "**TH**".

I'm using **UI component** & **Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection**. But don't know how to show only region that belong to "**country_id**" = "**TH**".

Can anyone help me please ? I really appreciate your help. 
Here is my xml file in Ui component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add Item</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="customaddress_region_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">RegionGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">block_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/save"/>
                        <item name="deleteUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/delete"/>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <container name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </container>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">region_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customaddress/region/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete these selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bottom</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="20" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">20</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="30" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">30</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="50" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">50</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="100" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">100</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="200" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">200</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="customaddress_region_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">region_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <column name="region_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="code">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Region Code</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="default_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Default Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Magebuzz\Customaddress\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\RegionActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">region_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: Are you show .xml file in ui_component folder?

Comment: I've just added that .xml file.

Answer (score 0):

This code below working for me. You can try:

**etc/di.xml:**

```
    <virtualType name="Your/VirtualName" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">directory_country_region</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="customaddress_region_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Your/VirtualName</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

**view/adminhtml/ui_component/your_file.xml:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--
   /**
    * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
    * See COPYING.txt for license details.
    */
     -->
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add Item</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="customaddress_region_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">block_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/save"/>
                    <item name="deleteUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/delete"/>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </bookmark>
    <container name="columns_controls">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_columns</item>
                </item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </container>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_columns</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filters>
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">region_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customaddress/region/massDelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete these selected items?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bottom</item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="20" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">20</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="30" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">30</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="50" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">50</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="100" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">100</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="200" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">200</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</container>
<columns name="customaddress_region_columns">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
            </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_columns.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customaddress_region_listing.customaddress_region_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">region_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>

    <column name="region_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="code">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Region Code</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="default_name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Default Name</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Magebuzz\Customaddress\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\RegionActions">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">region_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
</columns>
```

**Image success: 511 records found** 
[image]

Notice: You need change some params and agruments with your modules.